# Applying RadioButton style not working Android

Tags: android

So i searched online for answer and i cant find it anywhere. Anyway i was trying to apply some custom style to all RadioButton-s in my App but it's seems not to be working. Am i doing something wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name = "android:radioButtonStyle">@style/myRadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name = "myRadioButtonStyle" parent = "@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton" >
    <item name = "colorControlNormal">#ff9e060c</item>
    <item name = "colorControlActivated">#ff9e060c</item>
    <item name = "colorControlHightlight">#ff9e060c</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I m having the same problem, on 20+ works like a charm, but backward it doesn't, meanwhile, I have applied the style attribute to each component, I even change from radioButton to appCompatRadioButton with no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, try to apply style to `RadioGroup` instead of applying it to `RadioButton`.